# how do I redirect a folder name as url param using htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess

I need to 301 redirect in .htaccess from old site with folder structure to new page that uses the ending folder name as a url param.

like this:

http://example.com/artists/artist-name

to

http://example.com/search-works.php?searchArtist=artist-name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a couple options:

```
RewriteRule ^artists/artist-name$ /search-works.php?searchArtist=artist-name [R=301,NC,L]
```

or

```
RewriteRule ^artists/(.*)$ /search-works.php?searchArtist=$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

Comment: 2nd option is exactly what I was looking for